# Warning: Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mcrypt, opencart

Este erro ocorre quando abro o terminal e rodo o Opencart:

> Warning: Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Minha versão do PHP é 5.4.17., e estou em um Macbook Pro com Mavericks.

Alguém sabe me dizer como corrigir?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se em seu arquivo php.ini se existem mais de uma chamada ao extensão mcrupt.
Procure por `extension=mcrypt` no arquivo.

Em sua plataforma (Max OS X) acho que o arquivo de configuração do PHP pode ser encontrado em /private/etc/php.ini, mas depende da sua instalação.

Você também pode procurar por algo como /etc/php5/conf.d onde dentro deste diretório pode ter vários arquivos de configuração separados por módulo como: `20-mcrypt.ini 20-mysql.ini mcrypt.ini`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A existência de mais de uma linha carregando extensões em arquivos de configuração do PHP é que costumam causar este erro.

Answer (score 0):

Parece haver algo no seu php.ini. Poderia verificar se o mcrypt é carregado duas vezes nele?

Para descobrir o path do seu php.ini:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```